# Methods for Lockbox Unavailable in Swift

Tags: swift

I installed [Lockbox](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox) via Cocoapods. I added it to my bridging header. I can get a Lockbox object with `let lockbox = Lockbox()` and swift recognizes that a Lockbox is a type it knows about, so I *think* my bridging header is picking up the file fine. But I can't call any of the class's methods.

Lockbox has a method:

`+(NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key;`

I would think I should be able to access that by doing this:

`let aString = lockbox.stringForKey("someKey")` or  `let aString = Lockbox().stringforKey("someKey")`

But I get the error "'Lockbox' does not have a member named 'stringForKey'." What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of Lockbox's methods are class methods, but you're trying to call `stringForKey()` on an instance. The code you want is:

```
let aString = Lockbox.stringForKey("someKey")
```